# MKMapView move from one Coordinate to another animation

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkmapview

I am trying to do some animation about map moving. So when the user click on one point on the map, the map view will zoom in up to the space and then zoom out to the point. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To change mapView camera , set it to a region whatever it is with `animated:true`, like this

```
    var region:MKCoordinateRegion=MKCoordinateRegion()
    region.center.latitude =  // set lat;
    region.center.longitude = // set lon;        
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.090;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.090;
    region = self.mapView.regionThatFits(region)
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is after this zoom in, I still want the map could zoom back to the previous zoom level.

Comment: save the center coordinate with the old specified region